# Open source alternatives to commercial finite element softwares

Tags: open-source, cad, scientific-computing

I'm looking for Open Source alternatives to *commercial Finite Element softwares* such as **Ansys** or **Nastran/Patran**. Some features that I would like to have:

- Mesh generator after importing a geometry file (`.igs` or `.stl` formats)
- Capability to import/export meshes from/to other softwares
- Material properties library
- Static analysis
- Modal analysis
- Transient and dynamic analysis (optional)

Which would you recommend and why ? Are there any available on *Linux* ?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages

Answer (score 0):

Try [**OpenFOAM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenFOAM) which is **Open**-source **F**ield **O**peration **A**nd **M**anipulation. It is greatly used for CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics). It can do Meshing, Physical Modeling and Solving with various CFD solvers. Here is an [OpenFOAM User Guide](https://cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide/) might be useful. Another tool is [ParaView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ParaView) very useful for post-processing i.e visualization. I believe the combination of OpenFOAM and Paraview would satisfy your most of the requirement.

It is easily available for GNU/Linux distributions (refer [this](https://openfoam.org/version/linux/)) and licensed under GPLv3.

Comment: CFD is not the same as FEM.

Comment: @EricShain CFD constitute FEA, FDM and FVM all the methods

Comment: I respectfully disagree.

Answer (score 0):

There are many open source solvers that meet your criteria. The main problem for the average user is that these are not full fem packages, you usually have to use several programs to do pre-, solve and post- processing. Anyhow, I would recommend you check the following:

- [calculix](http://www.calculix.de)
- [code-aster](https://www.code-aster.org/) and salome-meca
- [Elmer](http://www.elmerfem.org/)

Also check for pre/post processing:

- [paraview](https://www.paraview.org)
- [gmsh](https://gmsh.info)

That should get you started. There are many more, but these are very close to complete FEM solutions.
Good luck!

Comment: Please post separate suggestions in separate answers.  That way they may be voted upon separately.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.